# Table sometimes loads and sometimes crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So I'm downloading some images from parse and then displaying them in a table but sometimes it crashes and other times it works.

1) Download all the names of the users that the current user is following, then...

2) download files (PFFile) from parse which will be converted into images as they download according to when they were posted. Then, the table will populate as the user scrolls down, or viewing older posts by user.

the problem is that sometimes it crashes and sometimes it works and loads every image as you scroll down. I'm not sure what is going on but I think that the list of names that user is following doesn't download entire (crashe) and sometimes it does (works fine). That's my guess.

Error: "fatal error: Array index out of range"

1) Downloading the user list: this is called when "Feed" button is clicked

```
func getFollowingData() { 
    var followQuery = PFQuery(className: "follow") 

    followQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objs = objects {
                for name in objs {
                   self.followArray.append(name.objectForKey("userToFollow") as! String)
                }
                self.storedFollowArray = self.followArray
                self.loadFollowersImages()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Download user posts (Name and Images)

```
func loadFollowersImages(){ //downloading posts of people we are following

    photoQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects!{

                //username of post
                self.resultsHasNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
               //Images of post                                    
                var userPicsImageDataToDownload = object["userImageFile"] as! PFFile
                userPicsImageDataToDownload.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (userPicData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let userPic = UIImage(data: userPicData!){
                            self.masterUserPicsArray.append(userPic)
                            self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                })                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Displaying in Table:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //....configure cell

    cell.usernameLbl.text = self.resultsHasNameArray[indexPath.row] // works

    cell.mainDrawView.image = masterUserPicsArray[indexPath.row] // Crashes and sometimes it works

}
```

Not sure what is going on. Has this happened to anyone else? what is the best course of action to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrap the reload of the table in a dispatch_sync

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in
  self.masterUserPicsArray.append(userPic)
  self.resultsTable.reloadData()
});
```

edit:

which array is the number of rows based on for your table view? cause if the resultsHasNameArray and the masterUserPicsArray update independently, then that can be a problem with determining how many rows to show in your table

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it's just black with the loading thing spinning on the status bar. What does dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in}) do exactly?

Comment: it will run the code in the block on the main thread, any UI updates must happen on the main thread otherwise you get weird delays happening in your UI. since you are using `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` im assuming the code in the block doesnt happen on the main thread and its being run on a background thread

Comment: something else must be changing your arrays in the background and then when scrolling your table is out of sync with your data, so its trying to access an index thats outside the bounds of the array, try doing more things on the main thread and see if it starts working

Comment: also which array is the number of rows based on for your table view? cause if the `resultsHasNameArray` and the `masterUserPicsArray` update independently, then that can be a problem with determining how many rows to show in your table

Comment: right, I see. OMG, now that you mention it, I was using resultsHasNameArray.count for numberOfRowsInSection. This is why it was crashing. I just changed it to masterUserPicsArray.count and it works!!! though, i removed the dispatch_syc(...) you recommonded. I need to study things about the main thread.

Comment: ah, ill update the answer to reflect that. tableview.reloadData() might not need to be run on the main thread then, otherwise those blocks are called on the main thread for you maybe.